# How to draw different geometric figures like circle on a page of stackedwidget using QPainter in qt c++?

Tags: c++, qt

I just started coding in qt and I want to draw a circle on a particular page of the stackedwidget. When I searched about this I got to know about QPainter class and while I am trying to implement this in my project it is not displaying anything, although there are no errors in my code.

I can't understand why it is not displayed.
I created a class named page_4 (this is the page where i want to display) inherited from QWidget class.

Following is a part of my mainwindow.h.

```
class page_4:public QWidget{

public:

  page_4(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

~page_4();

virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *paint); };
```

This is a part of my mainwindow.cpp:

```
void page_4::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{    
    QPainter painter(this);

    QPen pen;
    pen.setColor(Qt::black);
    painter.setPen(pen);
    painter.drawEllipse(400,100,80,80);
}
```

where as when I run the same code in a fresh new project it runs perfectly.

I guess in my project, I need to specify on which page it should draw the circle. But how to do that?
(I edited my question after trying suggestions from comments).

Someone please help me!!

Comment: If you override `MainWindow::paintEvent()`, then it's painted into the `MainWindow`. If you want to paint it into a stacked widget, then you should consider to override the `paintEvent()` of that stacked widget.

Comment: To draw into a certain page of a `QStackedWidget`, it could help to consider the [`currentIndex()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html#currentIndex-prop). E.g. `if (currentIndex() == paintIndex) { /* your paint stuff */ } else QStackedWidget::paintEvent(event);`. However, I'm still not sure whether this can work. For a certain page, a widget has to be added to the stacked widget. I suspect that child widget might clip your painting away. Wouldn't it be better to derive a `QWidget`, override its `paintEvent()`, and add it as child widget to the stacked widget?

Comment: What is the purpose of this? How you should do this, that depends on what you are trying to achieve, exactly. The simple answer is: create custon QWidget subclass which just paints the circle, and use that like you'd use any widget (say, QLabel with circle image in it).

Comment: Your example contains drawing on the main window. You need to implement `paintEvent()` of that exact widget, which serves as a page for QStackedWidget. So,   you create a custom one, paint on it and either propagate stackwidget's page to it (in Creator) or, better, place in on the desired page, so that it fills all of it (layout helps).

Comment: Still after trying all your suggestions i am not getting a circle on any page. FYI  i have edited my post. Please tell me if i did any thing wrong or i haven't done as you said!